# What's the closest thing to `std::atomic<std::vector>`?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, stdvector, stdatomic

I'm new to `std::atomic`.  If I understand it correctly, such variables can't be accessed by more than one thread at a time, and threads are forced to take turns if they try to do so.

I have an `std::vector<std::string>` that I need to make atomic.  What's the simplest, most fool-proof way to do this?

I have 2 threads.  One occasionally pushes strings into the vector, and the other thread continuously reads then erases all strings from the vector.

## Thread 1, DLL 1

```cpp
// about one per second
// this function is exported from DLL 2
myVector.push_back(myString);
```

## Thread 2, DLL 2

```cpp
 while (true) {
        if (myVector.size() > 0) {
            std::string myString = myVector.at(0);
            std::string myCopy;
            myCopy.assign(myString);
            myVector.erase(myVector.begin());
        }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a lock-free queue. Boost has one. If your strings have a small upper-bound on length, you can use a fixed-size struct.  Otherwise handing ownership of a `std::string` object from one thread to another might be viable.

Comment: Protect it with a `std::mutex`?

Comment: Remember that you don't usually want to protect a single operation on a `vector`. You want to protect the whole transaction. If you atomically verify an index is valid and then atomically get the value at the index, another thread can sneak in between the two operations and render the index invalid.

Comment: Is it really as simple as enclosing my critical code in `std::mutex myMutex;  myMutex.lock();` and `myMutex.Unlocked();`?  Really?  Is that it?  I'm looking at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/lock/) article.

Comment: Pretty much.  Or for an RAII-style solution, consider [std::mutex::scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock)

Comment: Don't just prefer the `scoped_lock`, use it like your program's life depends on it. It probably will. Just like it's really easy to accidentally miss a `delete` and leak memory, it, its easy to miss an unlock and deadlock the program. RAII makes it all-but-impossible to miss unlocking.

Comment: To be clear, the reason you’re getting suggestions about using a mutex is that `std: atomic` is not the right tool here. It applies to hardware types, not the more general types that programming languages build on top of those hardware types.

Comment: I tried `std::mutex` and it didn't solve my race problem, could it be because both threads are in different `.dll`s?

Comment: Make sure both sides are using the same `mutex` object..

Comment: I got it working with a `CRITICAL_SECTION`.  I didn't know enclosing code in that could work in a low-level language like C++, it doesn't seem like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of having "simplest, most fool-prof thing" and the goal to handle a complex data structure as `atomic` contradict each other.

One way of pursuing your goal is to have lock-based approach. The comments are suggesting that. Generally, lock-based approach has its own caveats (with deadlocks and starvations), but for your case it will work, though may be still sub-optimal.

What you need seems like a produce-consumer queue. Single producer, single consumer.

---

If you have the expectation of high performance, it should be lock-free, ring-buffer based.

[`boost::lockfree::spsc_queue`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) is one possible implementation. There are other implementations.

Also you may want to avoid string allocation and have `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<char>`, and delimit strings by `\0`.

If you want even faster that that, you may have own implementation, optimized for your scenario.

---

But if you say "One *occasionally* pushes strings into the vector", and occationally means *infrequently*, you may want lock-based queue instead.

Boost.Thread has [Synchronized Queues -- EXPERIMENTAL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html#thread.sds.synchronized_queues). There are other implementations.

The advantage of that instead of using `mutex` / `condition_variable` directly is that you don't have to write your own synchronization, so it really meets "simplest, most fool-prof thing"

---

I actually implement hybrid approach in my program. Which turns to lock-based when it needs to wait, but otherwise is lock-free. I haven't seen a good open-source implementations of such, but I would like to see.